# Excel - Program a specific cell to change colour based on specific condition of another cell's colours

Tags: excel

I need some advice on how to set up a rule to change a specific cell's color that is based on multiple cells or column colors.

Example - cell A1 should change blue n color, should column B1:B15 contain a set number of colored orange and red cells.

What would the best approach for this type of rule configuration would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would include a separate cell, say A2, which returns a 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' value based on the contents of B1:B15 (i.e. looking at their values and not colours to see if the criteria you're looking for has been met).

You can then link the conditional formatting rule for A1 to the contents of A2.